# How to export a list files (.tiff) from HDF format (MODIS product) using gdal.Warp in python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff, hdf

I have a list of HDF files from MODIS product (see in attached). I want import them in python using GDAL library. Show my steps and explanation in the code below :

> ### 1. Import required libraries :

```
from osgeo import gdal
import glob
```

> ### 2. Define the link to the folders :

```
inDir="...inputs/modis/MOD13A2v061/"
outDir="...outputs/modis/MOD13A2v061/""
mask = "..../extent.shp"
```

> ### 3. Import a list files with glob

[image]

```
files_hdf = glob.glob(inDir + '*.hdf')
```

> ###### 4. After I want use a for loop to display HDF files and extract only
>
> ###### "NDVI" variable      # (index=0) using "gdal.open" function and after
>
> ###### I want export all the files in geotiff #format (and clipped them with
>
> ###### mask) using 'gdal.Warp' function ==> But a the end I have # error !!!
>
> ###### (see below my code step)

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff'}


for data_path in files_hdf:
        dataset = gdal.Open(data_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        subdataset =  gdal.Open(dataset.GetSubDatasets()[0][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
        ds = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS=outDir,srcDSOrSrcDSTab=subdataset, cutlineDSName=mask, *kwargs)
```

#### At the end I have this error :

> #### TypeError: Warp() got multiple values for argument 'destNameOrDestDS'

I think the problem provided when exported the files with gdal.Warp, can you help me to improve the script?

Many thanks!

Comment: You unpack the dict as arguments, but probably should use keywords instead (eg `**kwargs`). You could also use the dedicated `gdal.WarpOptions` for that instead of using the dictionary, but both are fine.

Comment: I forgot * in warp => thank you very much – 
Rutger Kassies for your help